# How to optimize SELECT * command using indexes?

Tags: sql, indexing, db2, database-indexes

I am new to indexes and I have big problem.

My query `SELECT * FROM TABLE` lasts too long.

Is it possible to optimize this for quicker result using indexes?

I know that indexes are useful with `WHERE` clause and similar but this is `SELECT *`?

I have over 200k records and of course they all have unique ID.

Will be enough to just create one index with ID column or what is the best strategy?

Comment: If you are selecting 200k records the delay is more likely in the transfer of the results from the db server to the target application (DB management suite, end application etc.). If you are selecting a small(ish) subset of the data and it's taking a long time, then it's likely indexes will help. This question is too vague. Post specific details about your table structure and a sample query that gives the issue

Comment: I am using DB2 database. It has table TICKET When I use SELECT * FROM TABLE IT RETURN 200K records but it is too long. If I want to return only three records on example SELECT * FROM TICKET WHERE NAME='AAA' it also lasts too long

Comment: This is basically some application that uses this DB. If user click ENTER without any filter  it will show him all results

Comment: But if user do some filtering on example NAME column it will on example show him 3 results. Problem is that they have 25 fields they can filter IF they want it. So how to index this when I do not know on which field will they made filtering??

Comment: Will this solution be good - to create index containing 25 columns??? I will appreciate some help

Comment: Indexes won't speed up a `SELECT * FROM Table` query with no WHERE clause.

Comment: Hi thanks for help I have some progresses. I still have one dilemma. For this query on example which takes me too much time select * from TABLE  where (upper(COLUMN1) like '%HGW%'))  should I create index on COLUMN1 or not? Because of LIKE and UPPER statements that will maybe cancel its effect . What is your proposal? Will index have affect in this case or not? THANKS

Answer (score 3):

Don't create an Index on 25 columns. Create multiple indexes, perhaps even one for each column. If the users can filter on all of the columns, then make sure that the filters are AND rather than OR. If you OR between the filters then the indexes won't work as well.

Try this first as a test:

```
SELECT * FROM Ticket WHERE Name = 'AAA'
-- Take length of time that takes

CREATE INDEX IX_TICKET_NAME ON Ticket(Name)

SELECT * FROM Ticket WHERE Name = 'AAA'
-- Seel how long it takes now
```

If you see a big performance gain, then yes indexes will help. Then try to work out which other columns need indexes.

EDIT: Don't allow users to leave all filters blank then. Give them a warning to state at least some filters must be applied. Or if you can't do that, if all filters are blank just limit the results to 100 rows or something

Comment: Thanks this is very useful. Just to alrify something. My QUERY is always AND. But system works on that way that they can leave all blank and do a filtering! It is some IBM application and that is how it works

Comment: Also I can not limit to 100 results. It is the whole point of the system to see all records.

Comment: Hi again. I checked now and my application already has INDEX with just NAME column. But if I want to filter with this parameter my query again lasts too long. Why does it happen if it already has index on that field???

Comment: The system showing all 200k records if there are no filters is just not practical. You need to redesign that. Can you do `SELECT Name FROM Ticket WHERE Name = 'AAA'`and see how fast that is.

Comment: This is how IBM enterprise application works. I can not do nothing with that. If they want to see all they just need to click ENTER and will have whole list. I created NAME index but still when returning just 3 records it takes to 10 seconds. Why so long when I have index on that field?

Comment: Because it looks up the index and all it finds is the value in the Name column, it then needs to retrieve the other column values from the table. Did you do the SELECT Name FROM Ticket WHERE Name = 'AAA' ?

Comment: No I did SELECT *. I can not change that because that is List tab in some IBM application and by default it is Select *. what will be your  proposal then to speed it up if index cant help in this way?

Comment: Do you have a management suite that can connect to the database and run a query? If yes then please run the SELECT Name query to see if the response is quick. It would tell us if the index works for that particular query. Then you need to write a complete new application to interface with your table becuase an application that displays 25 column with 200,000 rows is not feasible in any environment.

Comment: Hi thanks for help I have some progresses. But I still have one dilemma. For this query on example which takes me too much time select * from TABLE  where (upper(COLUMN1) like '%HGW%'))  should I create index on COLUMN1 or not? Because of LIKE and UPPER statements that will maybe cancel its effect . What is your proposal? Will index have affect in this case or not? THANKS

Answer (score 3):

1. **For all columns you want to filter on, add an index** containing just this column.
2. In DB2, you can limit the number of rows returned by adding FETCH FIRST N ROWS ONLY, see http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.doc.admin%2Ffrstnrw.htm. This will be as fast as possible because **the first N rows are returned before all 200k rows have been found** (provided the search criteria is indexed).
3. **It is absurd to fetch 200k rows since nobody will look at all of them.** You might want to compute the number of rows (can indeed be done quickly using COUNT etc.), and show the first N rows only, see above. The point is to see how many rows are matched, not to see the rows themselves. I bet! Or you guys are 100% insane.

Answer (score 1):

The unique ID you are referring to is more than likely an indexed key as it is. Selecting so much data and working on it in an application is not going to be fast, especially if you are building a web-page. You may want to try:

- selecting portions of the data and processing it in parts.
- doing as much processing of the data as possible with sql on the database before showing the results in the application.